# Android Emulator - Take Screenshot and Adjust Resolution

Tags: android-emulator

To take a screenshot on the Android Emulator, I just need to click the camera button and that works well enough.  I am trying to get screenshots together to submit an app to Amazon and the screen resolutions that they require are:

800 x 480px, 1024 x 600px, 1280 x 720px,
1280 x 800px, 1920 x 1080px, 1920 x 1200px,
or 2560 x 1600px (portrait or landscape)

I'm taking screenshots on a Pixel 3 emulator and the screenshot comes out at 2160 x 1080.  The only way to get a usable screenshot out of this is to crop the image and I don't want to do that.  Is there any way to specify a resolution for the emulator so that I get the full screen shot?

Comment: Drives me up the wall that we have to provide screenshots with exact resolutions for this company ‍♂️

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem uploading photo to Amazon. Then I used [this webapp](http://convert-my-image.com/ImageConverter) to get do the job done. I made width: 1200 and height: 1920 and made it a .png file. Then uploaded it to Amazon.

This not be a good answer for this but it does the work.